# Nil while unwrapping optional Value

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

As title says getting a fatal error on the line with the **. Not sure how it could be nil though? It only happens after so many plays. Maybe because its getting a sound file from an array? Also happens every once ina blue moon in the didBeginContact function.

```
var soundFiles = ["gary1", "gary2","gary3","gary4","gary5","gary6","gary7","gary8","gary9","gary10","gary11","gary12","gary13","gary14",]
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

func setupAudioPlayer(file: NSString, type: NSString){
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: type as String)
        **let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)**
        do {
            try  audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
        }
        catch {
            print("Player not available")
        }
    }



func playRandomSound() {
        let range: UInt32 = UInt32(soundFiles.count)
        let number = Int(arc4random_uniform(range))

        self.setupAudioPlayer(soundFiles[number], type: "mp3")

        self.audioPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

```
// 1
var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody
if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
  firstBody = contact.bodyA
  secondBody = contact.bodyB
} else {
  firstBody = contact.bodyB
  secondBody = contact.bodyA
}

// 2
if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Monster != 0) &&
    (secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Projectile != 0)) {
 *** projectileDidCollideWithMonster(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, monster: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)**
}
```

Comment: If it is only working sometimes and not others, I would recommend adding in some safeguards and then print statements so you can see the exact circumstances of the crash. For example, add `guard let path = ...` in the `setupAudioPlayer()` function; then, in your else, print out what the parameters were. Additionally, is there any reason you use NSStrings as the parameters instead of just Swift's String?

Comment: no there isn't a reason. Could you possibly elaborate on your guard let path suggestion.

Comment: In that case I'd recommend switching them to Strings just to clean up your code. Here is what the guard statement would look like: `guard let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: type ) else { print("Path was nil with file: \(file) and type: \(type)"); return }` Then, your code would only go on if path wasn't nil (preventing against the crash) and if it did turn out nil, you could see what the file and type were.

Comment: Thank you sir, it found gary12 nil, which is what was causing the crash. Fixed it right up :) Any suggestions on the Physics?

Comment: I posted an answer to properly explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When code is only working sometimes but not others, I would recommend protecting against force-unwraps using guard statements to see the conditions under which your code failed. To rewrite the two methods you had problems with:

```
func setupAudioPlayer(file: String, type: String){
    guard let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: type ) else {
        print("Failed to get path – file: \(file) type: \(type)")
        return
    }
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)
    do {
        try  audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
    }
    catch {
        print("Player not available")
    }
}
```

This way, the code will only continue if you are sure that path isn't nil.

Similarly, you could try and debug the second problem using guard statements too. Here is an example of an updated if-statement:

```
if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Monster != 0) &&
(secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.Projectile != 0)) {
    guard let firstNode = firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode, let secondNode = secondBody.node as? SKSpriteNode else {
        print("Could not Cast nodes. FirstNode Type: \(firstBody.node.dynamicType) SecondNode type: \(secondBody.node.dynamicType)")   
        return
    }
    projectileDidCollideWithMonster(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode,      monster: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
 }
```

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: ran the game for a few minutes so far hasn't come up nil or crashed. Marked as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: @BARIIIIIIICODE Best of luck!